# Use different collection as reference without different set of code

Tags: .net, vb.net, listview, reference

```
If ListView1.CheckBoxes = True Then
    'using check boxes
    For Each lvi As ListViewItem In ListView1.CheckedItems
        'whole bunch of code
    Next
Else
    'not using check boxes
    For Each lvi As ListViewItem In ListView1.SelectedItems
        'the exact same whole bunch of code
    Next
End If
```

How can I select between two different sets of collections without having to duplicate my code? In my program I do the same thing with the CheckedItems that I would have done with the Selected items if my user is using Checkboxes. How can I make the collection variable without losing my reference to these items so I can write properties to them still?

Answer (score 1):

Use an "Extract Method" refactoring. Here's a trivial example, assuming that the two blocks of code are trivial already:

```
If ListView1.CheckBoxes = True Then
    'using check boxes
    For Each lvi As ListViewItem In ListView1.CheckedItems
        MethodCall(lvi)
    Next
Else
    'not using check boxes
    For Each lvi As ListViewItem In ListView1.SelectedItems
        MethodCall(lvi)
    Next
End If
```

1. Turn the "whole bunch of code" into a method that accepts `lvi` as a parameter. There may need to be additional parameters, but make sure that `lvi` is one of them.

   ```
   Private Sub ExtractedMethod1(lvi As ListViewItem)
       MethodCall(lvi)
   End Sub
   ```
2. Turn the "the exact same whole bunch of code" into another method that takes `lvi` as a parameter. Again, there may need to be additional parameters.

   ```
   Private Sub ExtractedMethod2(lvi As ListViewItem)
       MethodCall(lvi)
   End Sub
   ```

   The calling code now looks like this:

   ```
   If ListView1.CheckBoxes = True Then
       'using check boxes
       For Each lvi As ListViewItem In ListView1.CheckedItems
           ExtractedMethod1(lvi)
       Next
   Else
       'not using check boxes
       For Each lvi As ListViewItem In ListView1.SelectedItems
           ExtractedMethod2(lvi)
       Next
   End If
   ```
3. If you're correct about the two blocks of code being nearly identical, then you'll be able to make a series of small changes to make them *actually* identical. This may involve things like renaming parameters, changing the order of parameters, adding parameters, etc. Once they're identical, change the reference to the second method into a reference to the first, then delete the second method.

You will now have a single method that works for both branches of the `If` statement.

```
    If ListView1.CheckBoxes = True Then
        'using check boxes
        For Each lvi As ListViewItem In ListView1.CheckedItems
            ExtractedMethod1(lvi)
        Next
    Else
        'not using check boxes
        For Each lvi As ListViewItem In ListView1.SelectedItems
            ExtractedMethod1(lvi)
        Next
    End If
```

A tool like ReSharper is very helpful in this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put the similar code in a function

```
If ListView1.CheckBoxes = True Then
    'using check boxes
    For Each lvi As ListViewItem In ListView1.CheckedItems
        SimilarCode(lvi)
    Next
Else
    'not using check boxes
    For Each lvi As ListViewItem In ListView1.SelectedItems
        SimilarCode(lvi)
    Next
End If

Sub SimilarCode(ByVal lvi As ListViewItem)
    'whole bunch of code
End Sub
```